# A SqlPackage.exe warning fails a TFS build

Tags: powershell-2.0, sql-server-data-tools

I use a Powershell 2.0 script to publish a database with SqlPackage.exe.
But during the publication, I get this warning :

```
*** The following SqlCmd variables are not defined in the target scripts: DatabaseVersion PrimaryFileFolder DataFileFolder IndexFileFolder LogFileFolder.
```

According Microsoft, this warning is normal. If I run the script in a PowerShell console, the database is published with success, with the warning displayed in yellow. But if I call this PowerShell script in a TFS2010 build, the build fail because the warning is managed as an error.

How to do to suppress or ignore this warning ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens if the application used in Invoke Process activity produces warnings and errors on canonical error format. Please check this [blog post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/827dccd9-ebaa-4906-9267-0c4d90ad1677/a-sqlpackageexe-warning-fails-a-tfs-build?forum=tfsbuild) for detailed steps to workaround this issue.

Comment: The link goes to a social.MSDN answer, which has a copy of this same exact answer, but where the link in that answer goes to a dead url.